# using hook_form_alter on a same form from 2 different modules

Tags: forms

How will a predefined form behave if we have two different forms that implement hook_form_alter?

I would explain my question by an example, because currently I got a crash on it:

I have a predefined user_login form in user.module

I created two new blocks called author_login and creator_login. Each of these module using the form user_login and adding new validating properties for each form by using function hook_form_alter().

The new validating properties are:

For author_login block: if user doesn't have author role, user will not be logged into system, error: "you don't have author role"

For creator_login block: if user doesn't have creator role, user will not be logged into system, error: "you don't have creator role"

But the problem is: the new login block I created works fine if only one of two modules is enable. If I enable both modules, no user cannot log in to the system through these module.

For example, I have both modules enabled, I go to author_login block and log an user named Mark, who has role Author, to the system, an error message displayed: "the user Mark doesn't have creator role". And similar to creator_login block.

Why does this happen? I thought that the hook_form_alter will alter different properties to each new module we created, make each new form works separately. But from this case I encountered, it seem like the user_login form validate all new properties that I added by using hook_form_alter. And how can I avoid this as I want these two form to work separately?

Notes: I am really sorry to post this question here because I posted the question on drupal.stackexchange but there was only one answer that couldn't help me much in finding the solution. I really need help on this question. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All implementations of the `hook_form_alter()` will alter the `user_login` forms you embed in your blocks. As you observed, your author_login form alter will not be restricted to only altering the form in your author_login block.

If you want your form alters to only alter the form in the context of their respective blocks, you have to find a way to observe the block context from them. There is no easy way to properly implement this, you will either have to add additional non-standard arguments to your form builder (the arguments passed to `drupal_get_form()` after the form ID), or uses some sort of global states.

A cleaner solution is to use `hook_forms` to define new author_login and creator_login forms that simply re-use the existing `user_login` form as callback but have a different form id:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_forms().
 */
function author_login_forms($form_id, $args) {
  $forms = array();
  $forms['author_login'] = array(
    'callback' => 'user_login',
  );
  return $forms;
}
```

You can then simply implement a form alter specific to your author login form.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function author_login_form_author_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'author_login_validate';
}
```

And finally embed this form wherever you need it with

```
drupal_get_form('author_login');
```

Repeat for the creator login form.